# Creating recursively sorted RAR archive

Tags: filenames, sort, rar

For various reasons I decided to use RAR archive to store some data, instead compressed tar.

Happy with decision, except for one thing: I can't find a way to store files sorted. Order of files is important as I plan to query archive and results should be ordered.
My file structure is like this:

```
2000/
  001.txt
  002.txt
  ...
2001/
  ...
2002/
...
2011/
```

so folders represent years and files inside are numbered. Using `ls`, `tar` or any program lists files as expected.
If I try to create non-recursive `rar` archive (i.e. compress files only in folder 2000), files are stored sorted, but if I try to add files recursively (`rar a -r`) then files are messed up.

I can't find any switch except:

```
n@            Read file names to include from stdin
```

with which I had no luck to make it usable.

I could call `rar` on every file like:

`for f in */*.txt ; do rar a -r archive.rar $f ; done`

but that's not very smart.

Any ideas?

---

As I commented below answer, I though to update question:

I managed to store sorted files similarly as in above not so clever line:

`for d in */ ; do rar a -r archive.rar $d*.txt ; done`

which works fine for above particular scenario, of course

I haven't found how to use `n@` switch yet thou. I use `RAR 4.10 beta 5`

Answer (score 2):

Using rar on Ubuntu

(RAR 3.90 beta 2   Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Alexander Roshal   3 Jun 2009)

the best that you can do is this:

```
find * -type f | sort | xargs rar a ../eliezer.rar
```

Which you unpack with:

```
unrar x eliezer.rar
```

At least this does not call rar for every file.

The -n@ switch seems to work only for files. For example:

```
find * -type f | rar a ../eliezer.rar -n@
```

produces "WARNING: No files" if there are no regular files in the CWD, but

```
find * -type d | rar a ../eliezer.rar -n@ -r
```

works for the directories.

The rar recursive switch -r reads the file names in the order that they appear in the dirent struct (man readdir). So the only way that you could change the order that rar packs the files would be to manipulate the order of the files in the directory file structures (usually the creation order) before calling rar. You could do this with a directory editor, with the caveat that some file system types might change the order of the files in the directory structure as part of their garbage collection or optimization.

Comment: `find .` is more idiomatic than `find *`.  If you need to get rid of the "./" component, `find -printf "%P\n"` works.  If your tools can handle NULs, I would actually recommend `find . -type f -printf "%P\0" | sort -z | xargs -0 rar a ../foo.rar`, as it properly handles filenames with newlines.  Actually, I'd recommend `find dir -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 rar a dir.rar`, as it's considered polite in unix-circles to unpack archives into subdirectories.  The `-type f` is needed: the containing directory gets sorted before its files, and `rar` will pack them using the directory order.

Comment: Thanks Eli for your answer, but unfortunately none of provided examples stores file sorted here. I'm also on Ubuntu. `find * | sort` lists files sorted but `find * | sort | xargs rar ...` stores files in unsorted order for some reason. I tried also `-n@` (with additional `sort` command) which works fine as in your snippets, but again it does not store sorted files. I could provide screenshot from terminal if anyone requests it. So for me, snippet that works is the last update to my question: `for d in */ ; do rar a -r archive.rar $d*.txt ; done` which loops over folders and is acceptable to me

Comment: Either mistake in my original post or an editing error. I re-edited now. Should read `find * -type f | sort | xargs rar a ../eliezer.rar`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care how rar "stores" the data?
Wouldn't `unrar v archive.rar |sort` give you a properly sorted list?

Comment: Yes, I do, as I pipe uncompressed output to stdout with `rar p`. BTW `unrar -v` switch you mention, does not do anything here - did you test it?

Comment: of course I tested my complete answer, creating dirs and files matching the pattern you mentioned. the switch is `v` not `-v` (my typo)
I think that depending on how rar stores its data is likely to become problematic sooner or later. I would suggest tar over rar if you truly care about the internal data structure. Maybe use more than one tar file to reduce the overhead of updates.

Comment: Yeah, I started with gzipped tar and then wanted to update archive... rest is history, w/o even mentioning all handy rar options

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as stated in the Question and came up with this soluition:

```
for d in *; do find "${d}/" -type f | sort | rar a "${d}.rar" @; done
```

1. it lists all directories (only dirs in that folder!)
2. list all the files in one of the dirs
3. sort
4. use the @ without anything sin

Answer (score 0):

Information on this seems very sparse. However this question still helped me work out how to do it. So I'll post the process here for future searchers.

According to: http://acritum.com/winrar/console-rar-manual

> ```
> RAR command line syntax:
> RAR <command>  [ -<switches> ]  <archive>  [ <@listfiles…> ]
> [ <files…> ]  [ <path_to_extract\> ]
>
> Listfiles are plain text files that contain names of files to process.
> File names should start at the first column. It is possible to
> put comments to the listfile after // characters. For example,
> you may create backup.lst containing the following strings:
>
> c:\work\doc\*.txt         //backup text documents
> c:\work\image\*.bmp       //backup pictures
> c:\work\misc
>
> and then run:
>
> rar a backup @backup.lst
>
> If you wish to read file names from stdin (standard input),
> specify the empty listfile name (just @).
>
> Win32 console RAR uses OEM (DOS) encoding in list files.
>
> You may specify both usual file names and list files in the same
> command line. If neither files nor listfiles are specified,
> then *.* is implied and RAR will process all files
> ```

So the process would be:

1. Change to the root of the location you wish to archive from or use
   absolute paths. But be aware that an absolute path will end up in
   the archive too.
2. And then create the listfile

   `find topFolderOfTarget -type f | sort > listFile.txt`
3. Then run rar with @listfile.txt

   `rar a archiveName @listFile.txt`

Alternatively you can skip making a list file:

`find topFolderOfTarget -type f | sort | rar a archiveName @`

The reason this was useful to me is that I was creating a multipart archive and uploading it for a backup. If I only want a file or folder or 2 then I can simply get the relevant parts and avoid downloading the whole thing. Confident that the contents will be properly grouped.